# Tikz-timing: permanently change don't care (X) color

Tags: color, tikz-timing

The default color for a dont care is a very bright red. I know I can change the color the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{darkOrange}{rgb}{1,0.61569,0.61569}%
\begin{tikztimingtable}[]
  \scriptsize clock     & 7{C}                              \\
  Q                     &  HLX[darkOrange]X[darkOrange]X[darkOrange];LL                  \\
\end{tikztimingtable}%
\end{document}
```

But that is quite some effort. Is there a way to change the color of X for my entire project in one command?

Comment: Can you show a complete example, instead of a single line of code? `\busref` is not defined by `tikz-timing` (and possibly not relevant for the question?), and just adding that line of code into a `tikztimingtable` doesn't appear to do what you indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `timing/x` style.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\tikzset{timing/x/.style={blue}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
   foo & X \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```